# How do I output the data accumulated in mysql so I can export it in pdf using syncfusion?

Tags: mysql, xamarin, syncfusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXX6U.png)[empty list from same database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fplXe.png)

I have a listview that outputs data i wanted from mysql. it works fine but now i want to print that data.  There are 2 ways to do it excel or pdf. Using Syncfusion control will do the pdf and export it into a file.  My loop syntax is coming up empty when i  run it.  There are 2 columns that I made but the value from the mysql is not showing up.  I'm missing something but I don't know what.

This page is supposed to show data in pdf.  For loop code im having trouble with showing the data from mysql. it's empty when i run the code.

```
public HistoryLogPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
        {

            conn.CreateTable<Post>();
            var posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();

            postListView.ItemsSource = posts;
            conn.Close();            
        }
    }

    //to be able to know which item was selected
    void listviewhandle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedPost = postListView.SelectedItem as Post;

        if (selectedPost != null)
        {
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PostDetail(selectedPost));
        }
    }
    //this will print in pdf when pushed
    void filebuttonHandle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Create a new PDF document.
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

        //Add a page.
        PdfPage page = doc.Pages.Add();

        //Create a PdfGrid.
        PdfGrid pdfGrid = new PdfGrid();

       //List of Columns 
         List<Post> collection = new List<Post>();
         Post post = new Post();
         var Date = post.CDateTime;
        //column2
        var rain1 = post.rain1Lbl;

        collection.Add(post);



        //Add values to list 
        List<object> data = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
  //the line im having trouble with.....******************...
      Object row = new { Date = collection[i].CDateTime, Experiences = collection[i].rain1vol };
            data.Add(row);
        }
        //Add list to IEnumerable 
        IEnumerable<object> tableData = data;
        //Assign data source 
        pdfGrid.DataSource = tableData;


        //Draw grid to the page of PDF document.
        pdfGrid.Draw(page, new Syncfusion.Drawing.PointF(10, 10));
        //Save the PDF document to stream.
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        doc.Save(stream);
        //Close the document.
        doc.Close(true);
        stream.Position = 0;

    Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<ISave().SaveAndView("Output.pdf", 
"application/pdf", stream);
}
```

This is the source of my binding or data MODEL

```
public class Post
{
    //private const string V = "test";
    //from settingspage to show up in history
    string rain1lbl = Settings.rain1LocationSettings;
    string rain2lbl = Settings.rain2LocationSettings;

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public static bool showLabel { get; set; }  //public class model

    public string rain1Lbl
    {
        get => rain1lbl;

        set => rain1lbl = Settings.Drain1LocationSettings;

    }

    public string rain2Lbl
    {
        get => rain2lbl;

        set => rain2lbl = Settings.Drain2LocationSettings;

    }

    public string CDateTime { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string rain1vol { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(3)]
    public string rain2vol { get; set; }
    }

}
```

This is how I add to the data in mysql

```
    public AddrainsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        nameLabel.Text = Settings.NameSettings + "'s lovely rains";

        //For getting current time
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
          datetimeLabel.Text = "Date/Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM d, yyyy hh:mm tt"));

        return true;
    });

        rain1Label.Text = Settings.rain1LocationSettings;
        rain2Label.Text = Settings.rain2LocationSettings;
    }

    private void savemLButtonHandle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Post post = new Post()
        {
            //adding to Post.cs
            CDateTime = datetimeLabel.Text,
            rain1vol = drain1Entry.Text,
            rain2vol = drain2Entry.Text,
        };
//make a connection to database
using (SQLiteConnection conn = newSQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
        {
            //table we want to create
            conn.CreateTable<Post>();
            //now we can insert; insert in always integer
            int rows = conn.Insert(post);
            //only one connection at a time so we need to close it
            //conn.Close();

            if (rows > 0)
                DisplayAlert("Success", "inserted", "OK");
            else
                DisplayAlert("Fail", "insert failed", "OK");
        }

    }
```

Comment: your logic doesn't make any sense - you create an empty list and then add an Empty Post to it - you are not populating it with any data from your db.  It would make a lot more sense to just save a reference to `posts` when you first query the data from your db, then you could easily reuse this when printing.

Comment: so you mean this creating new list, I'm following a tutorial but its in different language so I'm trying to make sense of it:     //List of Columns  List<Post> collection = new List<Post>(); Post post = new Post();
        collection.Add(post);

Comment: How do i reference to post?  I think that's what I'm looking for.  I thought I needed to create new list to reference to post.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should maintain a reference to your posts data at a class level

```
List<Post> posts;

protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation);
        {

            conn.CreateTable<Post>();
            posts = conn.Table<Post>().ToList();

            postListView.ItemsSource = posts;
            conn.Close();            
        }
    }
```

then later you can reference this when building your PDF

```
foreach(var p in posts) {
  // add to PDF
}
```

Comment: how to add the column and rows.  The rows, I want to add post.CDateTime, post.rain1vol, post.rain1vol; The columns are colunn1 string "Date", column2 from post.rain1lbl, column 3 from post.rain2lbl.

Comment: i have syntax error:       foreach (var p in posts)
                {
                  Post row =  {Date = p.CDatetime, p.rain1lbl=p.rain1vol};
                  Post.Add(row);
 
                }

Answer (score 0):

On further analysis about the provided code snippet, we found that you have missed to add values to the object of Post class variables. Please refer the below code snippet for more details,

```
//List of Columns 
List<Post> collection = new List<Post>();
Post post = new Post();
post.CDateTime = value;
post.rain1vol = value;

collection.Add(post);

//Add values to list 
List<object> data = new List<object>();
for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
 Object row = new { Date = collection[i].CDateTime, Experiences = collection[i].rain1vol };
 data.Add(row);
}
//Add list to IEnumerable 
IEnumerable<object> tableData = data;

//Assign data source 
pdfGrid.DataSource = tableData;
```

We have created the sample for the same which can be downloaded from below link,

[Sample for export data to PDF grid](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/CreatePDFSample-631116340)

Comment: i ran the sample it's giving me sgen.exe error. I added the photo of error in my post.

Comment: what if I would like to get the whole data source from SQL by using the below query.  where would i insert this snippet?

string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Database.db"); 
 
//Initiate SQLite connection 
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath); 
 
//Assign data source  
pdfGrid.DataSource = connection.Table<Post>().OrderBy(x => x.CDateTime).ToList();

Comment: Please insert the mentioned query (only after adding values to SQL, if not it will be empty) while adding data source to pdfGrid. Please refer the below code snippet for more details,
//Initiate SQLite connection 
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath); 
//Add list to IEnumerable  
IEnumerable<object> tableData = connection.Table<Post>().OrderBy(x => x.CDateTime).ToList(); 
//Assign data source  
pdfGrid.DataSource = tableData; 
//Draw grid to the page of PDF document. 
pdfGrid.Draw(page, new PointF(10, 10));